# How to move point with mousepointer on shift-click in emacs

Tags: mouse, point, events

I want to write some functionality that fires whenever I shift-click a point in an emacs buffer.  Problem is that when shift is pressed, the point is not changing when clicking.  To make things more clear :

```
(defun mouse-test()  (interactive)  (message (thing-at-point 'word)))

(global-set-key [mouse-1] 'mouse-test)
(global-set-key [S-mouse-1] 'mouse-test)
```

When clicking on a word, the word is displayed, when shift-clicking it's not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually move the point in your function like this:

```lisp
(defun mouse-test (event)
  "Move the point to the clicked position and message the thing at point."
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((es (event-start event)))
    (select-window (posn-window es))
    (goto-char (posn-point es))
    (message (thing-at-point 'word))))
```

Do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>interactive</kbd> to understand how the argument `event` is given.

Also look at the function `event-start` for documentation about what info you can retrieve from the event parameter.

A function bound to mouse events will not move the point automatically, the function needs to do it.

The reason your function works with `[mouse-1]` is that you are actually running two functions but don't realize it. When you do a normal mouse click both the functions bound to `[down-mouse-1]` and `[mouse-1]` are run in that order. The default function bound to `[down-mouse-1]` is `mouse-drag-region` which sets the point.

However doing a shift click (`[S-mouse-1]`) does not run `[down-mouse-1]` so it does not set the point.

Run <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> then click the mouse and you will see the docs that describe the behavior of `[down-mouse-1]` and `[mouse-1]`

Comment: Unrelated note: Is there a recommended elisp coding convention where comments beginning on a new line begin with `;;` and mid-line comments being with `;`? **Update**: You removed the comment I was referencing :P

Comment: Yes there is a convention: `;;;` for doc and header comments `;;` for a comment on its own line, and `;` for a comment at the end of a line. However I just always use `;;` I don't really understand how the convention is beneficial.

Comment: @JordonBiondo: The convention is linked to the indentation behavior of commands such as `comment-dwim` and `comment-region`. Or rather, the reverse: the indentation behavior supports the convention.

Comment: I have [noticed](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-projectile.el#L107-109) that use of `;` vs `;;` affects auto indentation.